Do we need an inbound endpoint when sending data from oracle db(onpremise) to dms? In what terms do we need outboundendpoint for?
I'm trying to send data from oracle db(onpremise) to aws dms through direct connect gw. But I don't know whether I should use both inbound and outbound endpoint for route 53. I'm planning to use the oracle side's DNS.
Currently on cloudformation and haven't deployed anything yet.

the "aws_dms_user" will need access to the instance running oracle, so you will need inbound and outbound dms.
